# Updating the name of nb file after closing/running it

Tags: notebooks

Suppose I have a nb file named as `240119.nb` [date of today]. Now If tomorrow I open it and do something, then upon closing it, It should be renamed automatically as `250119.nb`. Any suggestion please ?

Comment: This saves a copy of the current Notebook: NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NotebookDirectory[] <> "new file name.nb"]

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command:

```
ClearAll[eventAction];
eventAction[]:=Module[{
    $previousPath,
    $todaysPath
},
    $previousPath=NotebookFileName[EvaluationNotebook[]];
    $todaysPath=FileNameJoin[{
        NotebookDirectory[],
        "NameChangingNotebook - "<>DateString[Today,{"Day","Month","YearShort"}]<>".nb"
    }];
    NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[],$todaysPath];
    DeleteFile[$previousPath];
];

(*DynamicModule[{},EventHandler[Null,{{"MenuCommand","Save"}:>(eventAction[])}]];*)

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],NotebookEventActions->{"WindowClose":>(eventAction[])}]
```

I am not sure about what the current notebook save event is called. It doesn't seem to be documented maybe someone here can help!

If the `EventHandler` doesn't work in the meantime when you are done with your work in the notebook, you can just execute the `eventAction[]` yourself.

---

Based on the suggestion by @Michael E2, I have added the `NotebookEventActions`. Try it and let me know @math if it works. Make sure to have a backup copy of your notebook in another folder!

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the desktop notebook frontend right now so I can't test it myself.

Comment: Would [`RenameFile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RenameFile.html) be safer?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't think you can change the current notebook's name while it is still open (i.e. from the same notebook). A renamed copy is necessary in this case.

Comment: @MichaelE2 do you know what the current notebook save event is called?

Comment: `"WindowClose"`, I think.  See also `NotebookEventActions`.